# codeIgniter framework 4 not working title

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

Earlier I'm used CodeIgniter 3 and after now using CodeIgniter 4 .

this is my view

```
 <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
```

this is my controller

```html
namespace App\Controllers;
class Home extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
         $data = [
            'title'     => 'My Real Title',
            'heading'   => 'My Real Heading',
        ];
        return view('blog_view', $data);
          return view('common/header')
          //  . view('home')
           . view('flip-flop-slippers',$data)
            . view('common/footer');
    
    }
}
```

But after showing this error

**Whoops!
We seem to have hit a snag. Please try again later...**

Comment: *"this is my view"* Which View are you referring to?

Comment: Please change your environment to development in your .env file so you can see proper errors and report back with the errors you're getting instead of a generic error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While loading the view, you closed the first view with a semicolon, then you returned the second view, can you try this way?

To which view you want to send the

> $data

variable, please send it to that view. I sent it here for the example at first.

```
namespace App\Controllers;
class Home extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
         $data = [
            'title'     => 'My Real Title',
            'heading'   => 'My Real Heading',
        ];
        return view('blog_view', $data)
          . view('common/header')
          . view('flip-flop-slippers')
          . view('common/footer');
    
    }
}
```

Controller
[image: Controller]

View 1

[image: view 1]

View 2

[image: view 2]

And result.

[image: Result]

Comment: thank you for the support. I found my issue i was send data wrong page

Comment: I'm happy for you, good work.